# set up an application with a database - tapestry-hibernate fail

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tapestry

I'm trying to set up an pom.xml for my web app to connect with database. The problem occurs, when I change `<artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>` to `<artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>`.

Here is output when I try to build:

```
The POM for org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-hibernate:jar:5.4-beta-24 is missing, no dependency information available
The POM for unknown.binary:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 2.177s
Finished at: Mon Mar 30 20:18:00 CEST 2015
Final Memory: 6M/15M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal on project TapestryApp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.rile:TapestryApp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.tapestry:tapestry-hibernate:jar:5.4-beta-24 in https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of apache-staging has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I'm using latest version of NetBeans IDE.

Here is full pom.xml file:

```
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rile</groupId>
    <artifactId>TapestryApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>TapestryApp</name>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- To set up an application with a database, change the artifactId below to
        tapestry-hibernate, and add a dependency on your JDBC driver. You'll also
        need to add Hibernate configuration files, such as hibernate.cfg.xml. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Include the Log4j implementation for the SLF4J logging framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Uncomment this to add support resource minification and runtime compilation -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- Uncomment this to add support for file uploads: -->
        <!--
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-upload</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <!-- A dependency on either JUnit or TestNG is required, or the surefire plugin (which runs the tests)
        will fail, preventing Maven from packaging the WAR. Tapestry includes a large number
        of testing facilities designed for use with TestNG (http://testng.org/), so it's recommended. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng-release-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
            <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
            <version>${easymock-release-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-test</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provided by the servlet container, but sometimes referenced in the application
        code. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-release-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Provide dependency to the Tapestry javadoc taglet which replaces the Maven component report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-javadoc</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>TapestryApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <tapestry.execution-mode>Qa</tapestry.execution-mode>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Run the application using "mvn jetty:run" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Log to the console. -->
                    <requestLog implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
                        <!-- This doesn't do anything for Jetty, but is a workaround for a Maven bug
                        that prevents the requestLog from being set. -->
                        <append>true</append>
                    </requestLog>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>tapestry.execution-mode</name>
                            <value>development</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting/>

    <repositories>

        <!-- This repository is only needed when the Tapestry version is a preview release, rather
        than a final release. -->
        <repository>
            <id>apache-staging</id>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <tapestry-release-version>5.4-beta-24</tapestry-release-version>
        <servlet-api-release-version>2.5</servlet-api-release-version>
        <testng-release-version>6.5.2</testng-release-version>
        <easymock-release-version>3.0</easymock-release-version>
        <slf4j-release-version>1.7.7</slf4j-release-version>

    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This version of tapestry-hibernate is not available in the [maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tapestry/tapestry-hibernate) neither in [Apache staging repository](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/org/apache/tapestry/tapestry-hibernate/) (you refer to it in your POM file).

If you want to go with the beta version then I suggest you to take the latest available (for example [this one](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/org/apache/tapestry/tapestry-hibernate/5.4-beta-28/)).

**EDIT:**

in the end of your POM file you have a property:

```
<tapestry-release-version>5.4-beta-24</tapestry-release-version>
```

change it to:

```
<tapestry-release-version>5.4-beta-28</tapestry-release-version>
```

**EDIT2:**

BTW, you define the following dependency twice:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
    <artifactId>tapestry-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>${tapestry-release-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

which does no harm at the moment but you'd better clean it up.

Comment: Wait, I'm really new to this things. How should I update my web app to this versions ? Is there any way to make this to work with hibernate ?

Comment: Thank you, build succeeded!

Comment: @Kapparino I've updated the answer from `26` to `28` since I haven't initially noticed that your POM refers to Apache staging repo.

Comment: Ok, I will change it now to beta-28. Thanks for that note!

Comment: Hey, I have one more question. I created an instance of `org.hsqldb.Session` class, and I'm trying to call methods like `session.persist()` and `createCriteria()`, but they do not exists. is that again duo to some version? I'm using 2.3.2v for hsqldb, I'm not sure which version I should use in order to use this methods I talk about above.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out myself. Netbeans called wrong package `org.hsqldb.Session`  instead `import org.hibernate.Session;`